# Cryptography best practices standard

Tags: cryptography, standards

I have been searching some standards about cryptography best practices.  I have found some articles and books but no official standard.

Do cryptography best practices standard exist?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're looking for?

Comment: Different standards exist in different domains.  For use with credit cards, PCI DSS is a security standard that has some cryptographic elements in it.  Financial transactions use ANSI/ISO standards.  For use with US Government covered systems, NIST has a comprehensive set of standards.  But there is not one overarching "Crypto Best Practice" that everyone adheres to.

Answer (score 1):

The ISO provide standards on many things, including cryptographic procedures: [ISO/IEC 19790:2012](https://www.iso.org/standard/52906.html)

I did a quick search on their site for cryptography and found a bunch of others including [hash](https://www.iso.org/standard/67173.html) standards and [secure financial services](https://www.iso.org/standard/61137.html) standards.

Only downside with ISO is that you often have to pay to get full access to the standards, so sometimes you'll have to do some googling to find a preview.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague. Not sure if you want to develop your own crypto (not recommended), implement it in a specific language (a question for stackoverflow, probably), or if you want just a set of standards.

For the latter: [NIST Cryptographic Standards and 
Guidelines Development Process](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/ir/2016/NIST.IR.7977.pdf)